# python list mutation in loops, global modifying vs. local modifying

Tags: list, python-2.7, loops, scope

Halp, perhaps someone more experienced than I am with Python can answer this (noobish) question.

I'm having trouble figuring out why the following behavior occurs with lists.

Let's have the following functions:

```
def foo1(L):
   """
    L is a list
   """
   L = ['new', 'stuff']
   print L

def foo2(L):
   """
    L is a list
   """
   L[:] = ['new', 'stuff']
   print L
```

IDLE outputs the following:

```
>>>L = [1,2,3]  
>>>foo1(L)  
['new', 'stuff']  
>>>L  
[1,2,3]  

>>>foo2(L)  
['new', 'stuff']  
>>>L  
['new', 'stuff']
```

I can't figure out why the first function only temporarily modifies the list, but the second modifies the list globally. I don't think it's a scope issue, but rather an issue with L= versus L[:]=

I know that if I use list comprehension to change L or use something like L.append() or some other method to mutate L within a function, then it modifies L globally, too.

I'm not all the new to Python, but, usually, I just google for solutions to my problems when coding, and, if it works, I don't question it. I'm taking time this summer to actually learn best-practices and get at the meat of python.

**Edits:**
So Martijn decided to mark this question as a duplicate, but I disagree. The linked question does not address my question.

When a variable is passed to a function, the function creates a new environment with its own scope. The variables in this environment exist only in the scope of that environment, and nowhere else. Hence, when my list L is passed to both foo1 and foo2, a temporary list, L, is made within the scope of only that function call. In other words, prior to calling foo1(L), there exists a list named L which is equal to [1,2,3]. After the call foo1(L), a new function environment is made, and it contains a temporary list, also called L, which lives only in the scope of that function. If I modify L via L = [blah, blah, blah] within the function, nothing happens to the original list L. However, by using [:] on L within the function, the original list is now modified. Why? How does python know after it has created a temporary variable with limited scope, that it needs to modify the original one with global scope? This concept does not make sense to me.

Comment: You are *mutating* the list object contents, versus creating a new list object.

Comment: Best practices? [Don't mutate global state.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/148109/144373)

Comment: Furthermore, what is it about the [:] operator in the second function that tells Python to edit the global version of the list itself? From what I've been taught in school, both of those functions treat "L" as some temporary object that is passed to the function and exists solely in its scope. If that is the case, then I'm baffled as to how L[:] somehow tells Python that the temporary variable L it created is actually my list made outside the scope? If that makes sense.

Comment: In the scope of foo2, L is simply the list you pass as parameter, which you the mutate. The result will be the same if you give it a different name in the global scope, it will be mutated. Think of `L[:] = whatever` as the equivalent of `L.clear(); L.extend(whatever)`, then it may become clearer. Python does not createa a 'temporary list'.

Comment: You're kinda right about how some languages treat function scope but what you're saying is simply not (always) true of Python. This is why [mutable default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/) is such a common "gotcha". When you pass a potentially large object to a function (such as a list or dict), Python doesn't make a temporary copy of it (pass by value), it more or less passes a pointer. This is oversimplified but it boils down to an implied pass by reference, which is why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Both the argument L and the global variable L refer to the same objects in memory. When you pass the object it is just a reference to the global object since that is how references and assignment work in python.
So when you do `['new', 'stuff']` in `foo1` you assign the value to `L` the local copy i.e. the argument since that is the first lookup for the assignment.
But on doing `L[:] = ['new', 'stuff']` in `foo2` you are doing a slice which affects the global variable.

You can test this by checking that the id is same for both the global and the parameter `L`.

```
L = [1, 2, 3]

B = L

id(B) == id(L)    # True

def foo(L):
   print(id(L) == id(B))

foo(L)    # TRUE

# or..

def foobar(L):
    print(id(locals()['L']) == id(globals()['L']))
```

Hope this helps. :)